# How to overlay point co-ordinates on tmap shapefile?

Tags: r, ggmap

So far, I've managed to visually present data for different socio-economic factors at a district level in Pakistan with the help of the *tmap* package in **RStudio** to create the following output.

[image: Electricity in Schools]

At the same time, I have used the *ggmap* package to plot the geographic co-ordinates of various towers for different Mobile Network Operators in Pakistan (roughly 13000 towers). The output is as follows.

[image: Towers in Pakistan]

My next requirement is to overlay the second plot over the first, essentially showing the towers on top of the district wise electricity scores.

Any ideas on which packages I could use (as well as sample code) in order to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share your data? If we can see how your data is stored we can see how to plot it? See [how to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for help sharing data.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be done with `tmap`. Have a look at the [`tmap` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-getstarted.html), especially the [Plotting with tmap elements section](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-getstarted.html#multiple-shapes-and-layers).

In your case your code ought to look basically like this:

```
tm_shape(shapefile_with_electricity_data) + 
  tm_fill("Electricity_in_Schools_variable") + 
tm_shape(shapefile_with_MNO_data) + 
  tm_dots("MNO_variable")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [st_as_sf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sf/versions/0.7-1/topics/st_as_sf) function from the `sf` package.

I used it in one of my project:

```
boston <- st_read("../data/boston.geojson")
proj4 <- st_crs(boston)$proj4string

student_points <- student_info %>% 
   st_as_sf(coords = c('lng', 'lat'), crs = proj4)

tm_shape(boston) +
  tm_polygons('#f0f0f0f0', border.alpha = 0.2) +
tm_shape(student_points_rastered) +
  tm_raster(alpha = 0.7, title = '# of students')
```